Error while generating content using Gemini ai model
 const finalPrompt = `${prompt} ${information}`;
    console.log(`Final prompt: ${finalPrompt}`)
    let response;
    try{
        const result = await model.generateContent(finalPrompt);
        response = await result.response;
    }catch(e){
        throw new Error('Error in generating questions. Please try again.');
        
    }

In Production the Gemini ai is not able to generate content. But works fine on local host.
The error i am facing in production  : Task timed out after 10.01 seconds

Does it take less than 10 seconds locally?

The value 10.01 looks like a timeout value in your app or deployment configuration. Not enough details in your question to know for sure. I recommend changing timeouts to be a lot longer than 10 seconds. I expect that after the announcements at next week's Google Next event, Gemini might be very busy being tested worldwide.

How do i set the timeout longer than 10 second?

There are several SDKs for Gemini. Which one are you using? IIRC the Gemini request timeout is 60 seconds. Check the timeouts that you configured for Cloud Functions and put those details in your question. Remember, include the details we need and update your question (not via comments) each time we ask for details.
